# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid Master Multiple selection to Detail

Tags: oracle, plsql, grid, oracle-apex, interactive

I have a master detail Interactive Grid, all is working fine. As soon as I select a row on the master it populates the details interactive grid without a problem.

The thing I'm trying to achieve is that I want to select two or more rows on the master and populate all the data on the details grid.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found your question very challenging and it can be useful to other users.

I'm not sure if the proposed solution works under every condition since it is not tested enough. I resolve your problem with `APEX_COLLECTIONS`, some `JS` and `PL/SQL`.

But lets start in the example below I will use the standard `HR` data set, more precisely the `DEPARTMENTS` and `EMPLOYEES`tables.

- In the `Before Header` section add one process defined as:

```
BEGIN
  APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(
              p_collection_name => 'SELECTED_MASTER');
END;
```

- Also create one `Ajax Callback` process, name it *SELECTOR*:

```
BEGIN

  APEX_COLLECTION.TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(p_collection_name => 'SELECTED_MASTER');
  FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count LOOP
    APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER ( p_collection_name => 'SELECTED_MASTER',
                                 p_n001 => apex_application.g_f01(i));
  END LOOP;

  htp.p('Done.');
END;
```

- Create the first `IG`: **Load Dept**

  - under **Source** section set the following values:

    - Location : *Local Database*
    - Type : *Table/View*
    - Table Owner : *Parsing Schema*
    - Table Name : *Department*
  - Columns:

    - APEX$ROW_SELECTOR (**!important**)
    - APEX$ROW_ACTION
    - DEPTNO
    - DNAME
    - LOC
  - **Static ID** : *loadDept*
  - on the `IG` create a DA:

    - Name : *SELECT_ROWS*
    - Event : *Selection Change [Interactive Grid]*
    - Selection Type : *Region*
    - Region : *Load Dept*
  - now add one True action which executes the following JS:

```js
var array = []
var i;
for (i = 0; i < this.data.selectedRecords.length; i++) {
  array[i] = this.data.selectedRecords[i][0];
}
apex.server.process( "SELECTOR", {
    f01: array,
},
{
    dataType : 'text',
    success: function( data )  {
        apex.region( "loadEmp" ).refresh();
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        apex.message.clearErrors();
        apex.message.showErrors([
                {
                    type:       "error",
                    location:   "page",
                    message:    errorThrown,
                    unsafe:     false
                }
        ]);
    }
} );
```

- The second `IG`: **Load Emp**

  - **Static ID** : *loadEmp*
  - under **Source** section set the following values:

    - Location : *Local Database*
    - Type : *SQL Query*
    - SQL Query

```
SELECT EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO,
       CREATED,
       LAST_UPDATED
  FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE
    APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_MEMBER_COUNT ('SELECTED_MASTER') = 0
    OR
    
    (
        APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_MEMBER_COUNT ('SELECTED_MASTER') > 0
            AND    
        EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM apex_collections
                 WHERE collection_name = 'SELECTED_MASTER' AND n001 = DEPTNO)
    )
```

Although it works the first record in the master table is always selected, and that is the only known bug or feature. :)

Comment: Thanks very much - just what I needed. Only diff is that I didn't want the detail to show any rows until at least one master row is selected, so I disabled "Select First Row" on the master region (under Appearance), and then the detail region query I simplified to:    select ... where deptno in (select n001 from apex_collections where collection_name ='SELECTED_MASTER')